# setSelectedItem in JComboBox do nothing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

My code is simple..........I want when I press button to set text to all labels in panel to " " (nothing) /which is working/ and all combobox to value 1. //which is not workig. It set only first combobox of seven in `ArrayList amout` to value 1, others don't change their values!

I didn't made `modelcombobox!!`Maybe that is the reason!
I don't know, I am beginner

my code

```
    public class Bill extends JPanel {
 private JComboBox amount1=new JComboBox(new String[]{"-1","0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5",  "6", "7","8","9"});
    private JComboBox amount2=new JComboBox(new String[]{"-1","0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7","8","9"});
   .........some other labels, combobox......

    static ArrayList<JLabel> product=new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    static ArrayList<JComboBox> amout=new ArrayList<JComboBox>();
    static ArrayList<JLabel> pprice=new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    static ArrayList<JLabel> prprice=new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    .......ArrayList to hold labels and combobox.....

     private JButton jbtView = new JButton("STAMPAJ RACUN"); 
       //conctructor

     public Bill(){

              product.add(product1);
      product.add(product2);
      product.add(product3);
      product.add(product4);
      product.add(product5);
      product.add(product6);
      product.add(product7);

      pprice.add(jlb1);
      pprice.add(jlb3);
      pprice.add(jlb5);
      pprice.add(jlb7);
      pprice.add(jlb9);
      pprice.add(jlb11);
      pprice.add(jlb13);

      amout.add(amount1);
      amout.add(amount2);
      amout.add(amount3);
      amout.add(amount4);
      amout.add(amount5);
      amout.add(amount6);
      amout.add(amount7);

      prprice.add(jlb2);
      prprice.add(jlb4);
      prprice.add(jlb6);
      prprice.add(jlb8);

    ......add all labels, bomboboxes to ArrayList , make panels......//all works
      jbtView.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                 for (int j=0;j<Application.manu.size();j++){                    
                     if ((product.get(0).getText()).equals(Application.manu.get(j).getName()))//this is working
                        Application.manu.get(j).setCol(kol+Application.manu.get(j).getCol());//this is working

                       }

                 for (int j=0;j<prprice.size();j++){
                     prprice.get(j).setText("0.0");
                 }//this is working-set labels to ""

                  for (int i=0;i<product.size();i++){

                      product.get(i).setText("");//this is working-set labels to ""
                  }
                  for (int j=0;j<prprice.size();j++){
                         pprice.get(j).setText("");
                     }//this is working-set labels to ""

                  for (int j=0;j<amout.size();j++){


                          amout.get(j).setSelectedItem("1");//only first combobox set to value "1", others doesn't change

                        } 
                      UKUPNO.setText("0.0"); // doesn't set to "0.0", doesn't change
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) *"DOES ANY ONE KNOWS THE REASON???"*  There is no need to SHOUT at us, and fix that stuck '?' key.

Comment: sorry from this code isn't possible something, post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with one JComboBox with hardcoded item...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean anything bad. Sorry again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you don't show us the constructor, th problem is pretty clear. You forgot to add all amount combo boxes to the `amout` array list.

If that is not the problem, check if you get any exception when you press the button.

Comment: no, I didn't forget to add to `amout` array list, that is not problem. My code is very long, so I couldn't put it all in this question!

Comment: Can class be to long? or confuse with many methods and variables? My has 400 lines

Comment: @Keva there is a limit to .java file size, but you would have to have hundreds of thousands of lines to hit it. Apart from it, no, there is no limit to the number of methods and variables.

Comment: yes, many.......`at Bill$1.actionPerformed(Bill.java:216)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)`  this is just a part

Comment: @Then you need to debug those exceptions.

Comment: I don't know how, can you give me some tutorial, please?